How to get as fast as possible a specific sequence of numbers (all numbers twice, except for the first and last) with numpy?
Knowing a final number (for example 5), I would like to create an array containing the following sequence:
[0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5]
Meaning that the list should contain all numbers repeated twice, except for the first and last.
Here is the code I use to achieve this :

import numpy as np

# final number
last = 35
# first sequence
sa = np.arange(0,last,1)
# second sequence (shifted by 1 unit)
sb = np.arange (1,last+1,1) 
# concatenation and flattening
sequence = np.stack((sa, sb), axis=1).ravel()
# view the result
print(sequence)


Do you think there would be a more direct and/or effective way to achieve the same result?

What do you mean by "more effective"?

@ScottHunter I mean direct and, as fast as possible. The example corresponds to a minimal situation. The final number of this script (last) would be much larger (something like 10 000 -> 1000 000).

What about using arange on 2*N, add 1 and take the floor division by 2?
N = 5

out = (np.arange(2*N)+1)//2

# or variant suggested by @TlsChris
# out = (np.arange(2*N)+1)>>1

Alternatively, with repeat and excluding the first/last:
out = np.repeat(np.arange(N+1), 2)[1:-1]

Or with broadcasting:
out = (np.arange(N)[:, None]+[0, 1]).ravel()

Output: array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5])
timings
Comparison of the different answers

Relative timings, around 10,000 items, the original answer seems to be the most efficient, otherwise np.repeat(np.arange(N+1), 2)[1:-1] is the fastest:


Replacing the division with a bit shift, //2 with >>1 gives a significant boost to the performance of mozway_division.

@TlsChris that's a good suggestion, although it doesn't seems to be always the case. I updated the timings.

It was the best so far :D See my answer.

If I may, I haven't played yet. A quite unconventional method (not without drawbacks. It has to be int32, so N is limited to 4 billions :D)
np.arange(0, (N+1)<<32, 0x100000001).view(np.int32)[1:-1]

Translated in base 10, it is a bit as if I were counting by steps of 101, on 4 digits, and then split digits in half. So 0000, 0101, 0202, 0303, ... turned into '00, 00, 01, 01, 02, 02, 03, 03', and ignoring the first and the last.
It should work with both big and little endian machines.
And on mine, it is faster than fastest algorithm so far.



Solution
timing for N=100000




jkguttormsen
2066 μs


dawao
843 μs


mozway broadcasting
817 μs


mozway repeat
549 μs


mozway division bitwise
361 μs


mozway division
301 μs


chrslg 64->32
33.9 μs



So considering the ratios between most of those solutions (excluding jkguttormsen's, ratio are in the order of magnitude of a factor 2 between worst and best solution),  that factor 10 is a lot. It comes with a price (the need to be type specific: could be adapted to have int32, int16, or int8, but not int64, and certainly not floats), but well, so far, it win the prize :D

That's a nice one, maybe a bit cryptic, but definitely smart ;)

You can speed it up even more: no need to clip the first and last value, just adjust the boundaries: np.arange(0x100000000, N<<32, 0x100000001).view(np.int32) (So, translating to base 10, this would be starting with 0001 rather than 0000, then continuing with 0102, 0203, etc. ­– though this might depend on the endianness of the underlying system). Incredibly elegant and clever solution by the way! I would have never come up with that one :)

Update: this would definitely depend on the system's endianness. Little endian solution (corresponding to my comment above l = np.arange(0x100000000, N<<32, 0x100000001, dtype='<i8').view('<i4'); big endian solution: b = np.arange(1, (N-1)<<32, 0x100000001, dtype='>i8').view('>i4')

@simon. Yes indeed. Hence the reason why I was lazy for the "remove 1st and last" part. Ensuring that all 64 bits numbers are made of "X,X" pairs, therefore not really caring how exactly X is encoded ((0,0,0,7,0,0,0,7) or (7,0,0,0,7,0,0,0) for a pair of 7 in big or little endian). Anyway, removing first and last is probably a negligible step compared to the rest. Unless N is small, but if N were small, OP wouldn't have asked that question :D

@chrslg I only realized that you must have noted this yourself already, when I reread your answer carefully and noted that you mentioned endianness already. So: sorry for that!

@simon. It is also why I stopped there, when, at first, I intended to remark that we could even go further, and count by steps of 0x0001000100010001, starting from 0x0000000100010002, and then converting to 16 bits. But that would require starting from 0x0002000100010000 rather than 0x0000000100010002, depending on the endianess. Not mentioning the question of "when to stop", that would imply some cases depending on N%4. And this times, in 16 bits, no way to be lazy and just generate an extra 0 and an extra N.

@simon. No, that was a good remark. If we know the endianess, that is the general way to do it. range from 0x2first32bitsNumbersPackedIn64bits, to 0x2last32bitsNumbersPackedIn64bits, by steps of 0x0000000100000001. Or range from 0x4first16bitsPackedIn64 to 0x4last16bitsPackedIn64, by steps of 0x0001000100010001. Etc. This is, after all, what MMX extension and other "vectorization" instruction of CPU do: hijacking 64 bits operations to perform 2 parallel 32 bits one, or 4 parallel 16 bits one, or 8 parallel 8 bits one. Of course, CPU have it easier, since they are self aware of their endianess.

@chrslg Thanks a lot for your extended answer(s). I learned a lot today (I rarely work on the bit-and-byte level of code, usually) :)

You might use numpy.kron for get each item repeated twice following way
import numpy as np
arr = np.kron(np.arange(6),[1,1])[1:-1]
print(arr)  # [0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5]

I create array with each item repeated twice, then slice to get rid of 1st and last element

That's an interesting idea, but quite slow. In the end this is equivalent to the more efficient np.repeat(np.arange(N+1), 2)[1:-1] (actually the fastest approach overall, I would have bet on the +1//2) ;)

Just a mini-demo; but this does the trick. Is it faster? For so short arrays, probably not something you would notice :)
a = np.arange(6)
np.array((a,a)).T.ravel()[1:-1]

Inspiration taken from here

import numpy as np

n = 10 

middle_part = np.repeat(np.arange(1,n),2)
print(middle_part)#[1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9]

res = np.concatenate(([0],middle_part,[n]))
print(res)#[ 0  1  1  2  2  3  3  4  4  5  5  6  6  7  7  8  8  9  9 10]

